# Define a property with a mixed data type in Swagger

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, swagger

I already have a working swagger document that generates documentation using the Swagger-UI project, but I'm running into a minor issue.

Mongoose supports a data type of `Mixed`, which is basically an unstructured object that can contain anything. However, according to the Swagger specification the only possible values for a property's `type` are `string`, `integer`, `number`, `boolean` and `array`. I've been unable to find anything in the documentation, on Google, or in the open issues for the Swagger-Spec project on GitHub that would allow for mixed data types.

In the Swagger-Spec documentation, where they define the `type` options, they refer to the JSON-Schema project. According to the JSON-Schema specification `object` should be an option, but it's not listed as a potential value in the Swagger-Spec.

Does anyone know of a way to indicate in a Swagger document that a model's property can contain any value (either a single primitive value or an object)?

**Examples**

Mongoose schema definition:

```
var sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lookupCodes : { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed] },
    address: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed }
});

mongoose.model('Sample', sampleSchema);
```

Usage of the mongoose model:

```
var Sample = mongoose.model('Sample');
var doc = new Sample();
```

These are all valid values for the two defined properties:

```
doc.lookupCodes = ['A', 'B', 3, 4, 5, 'F'];

doc.lookupCodes = ['A', { code: '123' }, 5];

doc.address = '123 Main St., San Jose, CA, 95125';

doc.address = { street: '123 Main St.', city: 'San Jose', state: 'CA', postalCode: '95125'}
```

Swagger 1.2 document (snippet):

```
"models": {
    "Sample": {
        "properties": {
            "lookupCodes": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "??????"
                },
                "description": "An array of lookup codes. Codes can be strings, numbers or an object containing the `code` property."
            },
            "address": {
                "type": "??????",
                "description": "An address. This value can be a single string, containing all the elements of the address together, or it can be a structured object with each of the elements as separate properties of the object."
            },
```

I'm simply looking for a way to let the developer viewing the documentation know that a specific property within a model could accept/return any value (primitive variable or an object).

Comment: Can you modify the question with an example of such model and where you'd like to use it (what parameter type, for example)? Your question contains contradicting details as the restriction you're referring to does not apply to models, but your theoretical solution doesn't seem to go in line with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @webron the simplest example would be a single property of a model that could contain either numbers or strings. mongoose supports this as option using the `Mixed` data type, but Swagger does not appear to have a corresponding `type` value that would allow this.

Comment: I'm not sure though how you think `object` would help there, which confuses me.

Comment: To clarify, I'll provide the answer but before I do, I want to make sure I understand completely what you hope to achieve.

Comment: @webron I've added a sample mongoose schema and a snippet from a swagger 1.2 document. Please let me know if you have any further questions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's actually an important detail. Do you intend to use Swagger 1.2 or Swagger 2.0? How do you generate the spec? Manually or using a library?

Comment: Actually, based on the edited question, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you describe two distinct use cases.

The first is the usage of an array with mixed values, and the second is a specific field that can have any value (be it an object, primitive and potentially an array).

Swagger explicitly doesn't support such modeling. There are several reasons for it, but they concentrate on determinism and language support. While dynamic languages can more easily support non-deterministic APIs, and weakly typed languages can easily support dynamic types, the other languages would suffer for it. APIs are meant for interoperability, being language-independent, so you have to consider these restrictions.

While Swagger is meant as a documentation tool, its ecosystem of tools includes solutions that would need to be able to produce and consume such APIs in virtually any language. Obviously, it cannot have 100% coverage, but it attempts to avoid known issues.

Swagger 2.0 adds much more flexibility in terms of defining models, allowing even free-form objects (and do note - objects, not primitives). While it would be highly not recommended to use in general, there are use cases where it just cannot be avoided, but even strongly-typed languages can deal with it (I can elaborate on the use cases, but it's not relevant to the question at hand).

As added information - think of it from a documentation point of view, and I'll use your `address` field as an example. What you're saying here, *API Wise*, is that the address field is a wildcard. You can accept *anything* to it, and it doesn't have to be an address, doesn't have to have a structure, doesn't have to have specific information. If someone wants, they can use that field to store a nuclear launch code. Now, if this is your intention, then just mark the field as a string value, and if someone wants to send a serialized JSON object as a string, it would fit just as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. My only counter to storing the values as a JSON string is that I'd then lose the ability to query for documents that contain certain values. Using the `address` example above, I could write a query to only return documents that have an `address.postalCode` value of `95125`. Granted, there could be all kinds of garbage in many of the documents, but mongoose/mongodb supports this. By converting the JSON object to a string I'd no longer have the ability to search for potential values.

Comment: I didn't say you can't *parse* the JSON string to an object, I'm saying that *API wise* it is irrelevant. Separate the two. I'm well familiar with mongodb and its capabilities. ;)

Comment: Good idea. I guess I'll just have to use "string" as the `type` and include additional information to the description of a property to indicate it accepts a JSON string. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ron, I have read many times about some reasons about determinism and how APIs "should be". The fact is that there are many APIs and standards out there that don't follow your statements, and it makes imposible for developers to describe those APIs. There plenty of dynamic typed languages and if a Swagger schema definition cannot support them, then you will be preventing a big portion of developers on adopting it, although JSON schema does support them. I am facing a similar situation and I probably would have to leave Swagger just because of that reason.

Comment: @Jaime - we're currently working on the next version of the spec. I've used the term 'determinism' a lot in the past, but it's not very accurate I'm afraid. We're currently working on the next version of the spec and things may change on that front. While looking to be able to support more APIs out there, we will not be able to support all of them.